# How to use React Customize Environment Variables inside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

I used Create-React-App to create a react application, now I want to have 3 different envirement variable for build :

1 - Development

2 - Staging

3 - Production

I follow  this [article](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables) from Facebook. So based on this artile, now I have 3 .env files in my project :

```
.env.development

.env.staging

.env.production
```

in each one of this .env files I have my API address based on the stage we are building the app, like this :

```
API_URL=https://MYAPI.com/STAGE
```

in my package.json I have these scripts :

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "env-cmd .env.development react-scripts start",
   "build_development": "env-cmd .env.development npm run build",
   "build_staging": "env-cmd .env.staging npm run build",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
 }
```

In my component which call this api URL, I use this to get the API_URL :

```
let apiUrl = process.env.API_URL
```

So once I run for example : npm run build_staging

It will build the app but once I debug it, `apiUrl` is always `undefined`.

Not sure what is wrong? anyone had such a problem?

Comment: did you restarted the server after defining the env variables?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar What do you mean by restarting the server? there is no server, it's just a client side react application, and I run npm run build_staging in terminal to build the app from scratch but apiUrl is always undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your environment variable names need to start with `REACT_APP_` using `create-react-app`, as stated in the [same GitHub page](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables) you linked. Changing your `API_URL` to `REACT_APP_API_URL` should fix the issue.